# Jmeter: __VIEWSTATE, __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR and __EVENTVALIDATION regular expression not working

Tags: jmeter

I have a series of HTTP Request Samplers where I have used regular expression extractor for __VIEWSTATE, __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR and __EVENTVALIDATION, which is working fine and getting response data also.

But in one step I am getting error "generalError:Invalid viewstate" after execution (only for this step) and my regular expression variable is displayed in the error message- ViewState: ${eventValidation}

I have tried a lot of regular expression

```
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="(.+?)" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="([-;,':\*\/\}\{\=\[\]\)\(0-9a-zA-Z]*)" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="([^'"]+)" />
```

All the above 3 types got failed.

Actual recorded __VIEWSTATE parameter value is

```
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
```

Note that above value contains multiple "/////"

Error displayed is:`0|/*DX*/({'generalError':'Invalid viewstate. \r\n\tClient IP: 61.12.77.210\r\n\tPort: 60301\r\n\tReferer: \r\n\tPath: /PPODevX/OrgSummary.aspx\r\n\tUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36\r\n\tViewState: ${eventValidation}'})`

Please let me know if anything more is required

Thanks in advance

When I hard coded __VIEWSTATE, __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR, __EVENTVALIDATION I got proper response data.

Please find below screen shot for Hard coded result.

[1. HTTP Request Parameters - Hard Coded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8fx3.png)

Screen shot for using CSS/Jquery extracter variable

[1. HTTP Request Parameter - CSS/JQUERY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqERi.png)

[2. VIEWSTATE - CSS/JQUERY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMm7t.png)

[3. VIEWSTATEGENERATOR - CSS/JQUERY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCvVj.png)

[4. EVENTVALIDATION - CSS/JQUERY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmQdS.png)

Response Data using CSS/JQUERY

```
0|/*DX*/({'generalError':'Invalid viewstate. \r\n\tClient IP: 61.12.77.210\r\n\tPort: 17420\r\n\tReferer: \r\n\tPath: /PPODevX/OrgSummary.aspx\r\n\tUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36\r\n\tViewState: ${VIEWSTATE}'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [CSS/JQuery Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor) element with below configuration:

[image: CSS/JQuery Extractor]

Comment: I tried your solution for both __VIEWSTATE and __EVENTVALIDATION but I got the same response data "generalError : Invalid viewstate"

Comment: It's because you have hardcoded the value. You need to make it a variable using ${VIEWSTATE}

Comment: Hi, I did not hard coded, I have used the variable ${VIEWSTATE} and ${EVENTVALIDATION} for __VIEWSTATE and __EVENTVALIDATION parameter value respectively. Still no luck.

Comment: There is something you are missing, the extractor need to be on the first request that generates the 3 values you are trying to extract, then in the following request you can use the vaues with ${} syntax.

Comment: I tried keeping extractors above this HTTP Request, still I am getting the same Response data "generalError : Invalid viewstate". Is there any possibilities like extract the __VIEWSTATE and __EVENTVALIDATION values and pass it here?

Comment: show please the request before and the request where you use the variables, all expanded.